# Proof of positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, positive-definite

Consider a matrix $X$ to be
\begin{equation}
X=P-PA^\top\left(APA^\top + Q\right)^{-1}AP,
\end{equation}
where $P\in\Re^n$ is a positive definite matrix, $A\in\Re^n$ is a non-singular matrix, $Q\in\Re^n$, such that
\begin{equation}
Q=\begin{bmatrix}Q_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $Q_1\in\Re^r$ is a positive definite matrix and $r<n$.

My question is: Is it possible to prove that matrix $X$ is a positive semi-definite matrix?

Many thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $X$ is psd. Note that $APA^T+Q\succeq APA^T\succ 0$ because $Q$ is psd and so 
$$
(APT^T+Q)^{-1}\preceq (APA^T)^{-1}=(A^T)^{-1}P^{-1}A^{-1}.
$$
Thus, for all $v$,
\begin{align*}
v^TPA^T(APT^T+Q)^{-1}APv&=(APv)^T(APT^T+Q)^{-1}(APv)\\
&\leq(APv)^T(A^T)^{-1}P^{-1}A^{-1}APv\\
&=v^TP(A^T)(A^T)^{-1}P^{-1}A^{-1}APv\\
&=v^TPv.
\end{align*}
The claim follows.

Answer (score 2):

This looks an awful lot like use-case for the [Schur Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement).

In particular, $X$ is the Schur complement of the following block matrix:

$$Z=\begin{bmatrix}
P & PA^T \\
AP & APA^T+Q
\end{bmatrix}.$$

A basic property of Schur complements is that when $P>0$, then $X\geq 0$ iff $Z\geq 0$.

By decomposing 
$$Z = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & A
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
P & P \\
P & P
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & A^T
\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & Q
\end{bmatrix},$$
it is not hard to see that $Z\geq 0$. Hence, $X\geq 0$.